# Python Script and Task Scheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

Looking for an answer on the following scenario:

I have a Python Script running, which i have plugged in my Windows Task Scheduler. Task runs successfully but does not do the work. Actually this script is supposed to download a file from SFTP Location Decrypt the file and converted csv file is being uploaded into the SQL Server.

Above Script is running fine when i run from the command line. however same script does not work when running from the Scheduler.

I have tried following approach to solve:

- Task is running with the highest privilege
- Task does not require user to log in, without login also task is running.

Other than above 2 options, I have no idea what needs to be done.

PS: From the task scheduler's history, I can see that there is no access denied error coming

Comment: You will obviously need to add appropriate logging or other diagnostics to your code to figure out what is actually happening.

Comment: I did added the logs but could not find any error coming from it.

Comment: Hi I did check the code is working in other than C drive but when i put my .py file in C drive and run from the task scheduler, it is not downloading the files from the SFTP Location. Any Ideas?

Comment: I'll just say I am having the same issue.  I tried wrapping the script in a .bat file.  Same issue.  it runs fine when clicked, but Task Scheduler performs no actions and returns no errors.  I tried building a C# executable to call the python script.  Same issue.  Did you ever figure out what the problem was?